# How to count or group relations from two colums with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know the basics of SQL but is not more than a beginner, so I have no idea how to search for this question the right way.

Question: 
How do I count matching relations in a two column set up? Example:

I use:

```
SELECT "from", "to", COUNT(*) Count
FROM "LocationDestination"
GROUP BY "from", "to"
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

which get me:

```
from        to      Count
Germany     USA     6
USA         Spain   5
Marocco     Spain   4
USA         Germany 2
Spain       Marocco 2
```

What I want is a table that lookes like this:

```
Destination1    Destionation2     Count
Germany         USA               8
Marocco         Spain             6
USA             Spain             5
```

Thus combining the trips Germany - USA with USA - Germany, and Marocco - Spain with Spain - Marocco, and so forth..

How can that be achieved?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: It is a SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way

```
SELECT case when froms > tos then  froms else tos end,
        case when froms < tos then froms else tos end,
        Count(*)
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY case when froms > tos then  froms else tos end,
        case when froms < tos then froms else tos end
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

MySQL - Use `least` and `greatest` to get only one combination in case symmetric pairs exist.

```
SELECT least("from", "to"), greatest("from", "to"), COUNT(*) Count
FROM "LocationDestination"
GROUP BY least("from", "to"), greatest("from", "to")
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```